# Bold text on meta seems difficult to distingush from non-bold

Tags: discussion, design, meta

This is regular text surrounding **some bold text** and not really different visually from it.

> This is regular text surrounding **some bold text** and not really different visually from it.

It seems better in the blockquote's darker background; but without one, personally I find bolded text to be very hard to visually distinguish from non-bold (Windows Firefox, site's default CSS, and not really affected by changing fond size too much).

Would it be possible to somehow change the color on bolded text (may be make it yellowish) to emphasize it more?

Or am I just being blind and nobody else sees this as an issue on meta?

---

Here’s a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?  It might just be a font issue on your computer.  Bolding is easily visible for me in your question here, on Firefox on Ubuntu linux...

Comment: @Izkata -- done

Comment: Firefox on XP here, and the bold/non-bold is a little difficult to distinguish for me as well.

Comment: I've always disliked the 'dark' theme on here. Just seems to make my eyes really tired every time I read more than one post...

Comment: @Mooz By 'dark theme here ' do you mean that the scifi meta site is duller than the main site , as in its less colorful ?